# Minimize the profit, job scheduling with deadline

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, greedy

I am facing problem in calculating minimum profit for given 5 jobs with deadline.

Profits are (P1,P2...P5)=(20,15,10,1,6) and deadlines are (2,2,1,3,3) respectively.
My solution for this question is:

```
+----------+----+-----+---------+
| Deadline | 1  |  2  |    3    |
+----------+--------+-----------+
|    Jobs  | J4 | J5  | (Empty) |
+----------+--------+-----------+
```

I left the last cell empty because after filling J5 and J6, no other jobs can be done in the 3rd hour. And according to this, profit is  7.

Is it correct?

PS: One job takes one hour and Only one job can be assigned at a time.

Comment: How many hours per each job? Should each job take only one hour? And how many jobs can you do concurrently? Only one?

Comment: @BassemAkl Sorry I forgot to mention, One job takes one hour and Only one job can be assigned at a time.

Comment: @BassemAkl Because It's not the minimum profit afaik

Comment: @greybeard Nooo..

Comment: `Sorry I forgot to mention, One` do not put such information in comments: edit your question. - What *is* `J6`? I take `J5` to correspond to `P5`. If slots/hours may be left empty and profits are non-negative, don't schedule *any* job.

Comment: @AmanSharma The minimum would be doing no jobs at all. There apparently must be a condition which prohibits this, but it is not in your question.

Comment: @greybeard I corrected that `J6` and I left that slot because once we fill `J4` and `J5` no other jobs can be filled in the 3rd hour as they are expired after 2nd hour

Comment: @lexicore No other condition is mentioned but not scheduling jobs is not the solution

Comment: To make the profit minimum, You should not complete any job at all. Do you have another condition for minimum number of jobs that should be completed?

Comment: @AmanSharma "No other condition is mentioned but not scheduling jobs is not the solution" - If no other condition is mentioned, then no jobs IS a solution. There MUST be other condition, otherwise the problem does not make sense.

Comment: @SanketMakani No, There is not other condition

Comment: @AmanSharma "No, There is not other condition" - Then no jobs is a solution. Period.

Comment: @AmanSharma Then answer should be 0 as to make profit as minimum as possible, You don't need to complete any job.

Comment: @lexicore Okay, I'll take this as solution, but I will mention the condition once I find any

Comment: I think all hours slots should be filled. That would be a logical condition.

Comment: @AmanSharma A reasonable condition would be "no additional jobs could be completed".

Comment: @BassemAkl I don't think it's "all N slots must be filled". This would not produce the J4, J5 as a valid solution and the OP gives it as an example.

Answer (score 0):

If it is **required to fill all hours slots, and get the min profit**:

I'd go this way:

1. Sort your jobs based on (deadline_max, profit_min): **J(4,5,2,1,3)** = **P(1,6,15,20,10)**, **D(3,3,2,2,1)**.
2. Start from the highest hour/deadline which is **3**. Only jobs with deadline = 3 can fit in this hour.
3. Take the first one (which is the lowest) = **1** = **J4**. Still the remaining of deadline 3 could be used for the lower deadlines.
4. Take the next value of deadline 3 which is **6** and compare it to the first value of deadline 2: If it smaller then apply this job, if not take first job of deadline 2. Because it is smaller then the job for deadline 2 is **J5**.
5. Now, jobs for deadline 3 & 2 are taken, and you want to check for deadline 1. The highest deadline acceptable for hour #1 is deadline #1. Take the smallest (which is the only job). **10** = **J3**.

Then the **answer** is : **J3, J5, J1. total min profit = 17**